# Error creating a .net core web application

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

In Visual Studio 2015, I go File/New Project, select `ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Core)` from list of templates, then select `Web Application` template from the dialog box.  It tells me that the .NET Core SDK version 1.0.0-preview2-1-003177 is not installed and that I should go to a provided link.

[image]

I go to the provided [link](https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/blob/master/known-issues-vs2015.md#missing-sdk), but it doesn't have that specific version.

Where do I go from here?

P.S. I installed VS2017 (released version) yesterday and everything went haywire from there.

P.P.S This is not a dupe of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140408) since I am not opening a project.json based project - it gets an .xproj file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't run .Net Core based on project.json after VS 2017 installation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41404087/cant-run-net-core-based-on-project-json-after-vs-2017-installation)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to reinstall VS 2017, when i first installed it yesterday all my big Projects suddenly had hundreds of Errors because i couldnt include some libaries and when i reinstalled VS 2017 it all worked smoothly again. This might fix your issue :)